# Cannot access textContent of HTML el but can console log it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

so i am trying to manipulate with table on this [website](https://cryptoroyale.one/skinwars/?date=live).

my script i insert in the chrome/firefox console on the website:

```
let skins = [
"button" //simplified 
];

skins.forEach((skin)=>{

document.querySelector("tbody").childNodes.forEach((k,i)=>{
if(i>0){ // starts with 1 because i==0 is #text
    
    console.log(k.childNodes[1].textContent); // this works in chrome,firefox
    
    let h = k.childNodes[1].textContent; 
    if(h == "shades") console.log("yes"); // this part doesnt work - error 
}
})

});
```

when i console.log it, it does work, and show all the `<tr>` on position 1. But when i try to do some code with if statement, the error message shows up,

```
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')
at <anonymous>:11:30
at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:8:44
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:6:7
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i didnt carefully set the boundaries, thats why i get an error. There was another `#text`
and the results also needed .trim() to remove extra whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing {}

```
if(h == "shades") console.log("yes")
```

do instead:

```
if (h == 'shades') {
 console.log("yes");
}
```

Comment: those two code snippets are completely equivalent. I don't personally like the first form, as a matter of style - but they should both work fine